# Tkinter - how to disable an existing button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to disable a button using Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os


class OptionWindow:




    def __init__(self, value):

        self.master = Tk() 
        self.master.minsize(500,500)
        self.b1 = Button(self.master, text = "save Game", command =self.saveGame, state = NORMAL).grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

   def saveGame(self):       
        from modules.startingKit import options
        options.saved = True
        self.b1.configure (state = DISABLED)
```

Yet, for some reason, when I press the "save Game" button, its appearance does not change.
What must I do to disable it?

Comment: Not sure if it matters: Have you started the mainloop? `self.master.mainloop()` as the last thing in your `__init__` function. Or bring the `Tk()` instance as a parameter to `OptionWindow`'s constructor and pass it to `self.master`.

Comment: I have...sorry I did omit that here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake, probably because there are several tutorials on the internet which make this same mistake.

In python, if you do `x=foo().bar()`, `x` is given the result of `bar()`.  In your code you're doing `self.b=Button(...).grid(...)`. Thus, `self.b` is set to the result of `grid(...)`. `grid(...)` always returns `None`. Because of that, doing `self.b.configure(...)` is the same as doing `None.configure(...)` which obviously is not going to do what you think it is going to do.

The solution is to do widget creation and widget layout in separate steps:

```
self.b1 = Button(...)
self.b1.grid(...)
```